# tell which whether day, month or year is invalid with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I know I can tell that a whole date is invalid with momentjs `isValid`:

```
moment(values.dateOfBirth, dateFormat).isValid()
```

But is there a way of telling whether it is the day, month or year part which is invalid?

e.g. if the day is 30 and the month is feb then it is the day that is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `.invalidAt()` to determine which date value overflowed:

```
var m = moment("2011-10-10T10:20:90");
m.isValid(); // false
m.invalidAt(); // 5 for seconds
```

The integer returned has the following meaning:

- -1 no overflow
- 0 years
- 1 months
- 2 days
- 3 hours
- 4 minutes
- 5 seconds
- 6 milliseconds

source: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/